# Configuration send mail for send my from

Tags: php, linux, server, sendmail

I setup sendmail in linux server, I use my gmail.com accaunt as mail collector. I can send mail to different mail address in web, but I can not set my field `from:` in mail, the `from:` always set as my mail address... How to I can set my custom email address on field `from:` in mail? 
p.s. sorry for my English.

Comment: You can't when using a free gmail account. That is because gmail takes the liberty to change your messages content.

Comment: Not sure you should be changing the from: content to start with. Most mail servers will check if the from: field actually matches the domain it was sent from and flag you as spam/spoofed if it isn't.

Comment: @TingSun Mail from php recived. And mail in from exist.

Comment: @arkascha fanks! I fink about it

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting header as:

```
$headers = 'From: username@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: username@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Then you can use: 
 `mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)` to send mail where `$to`, `$subject` and `$body` are self explanatory variables.

For more info: visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Which will get marked as SPAM by most receiving systems these days. Example: spamassassin scores 3.1 points for that!

Comment: True @arkascha, But It works if you want to send mail in your internal network where you can say people to mark that mail as "Not Spam".

Comment: But _why?_ Why not send out valid messages? I mean setting up a smtp server for this is a thing of 10 minutes.

Comment: This is only an issue if you are trying to specify `from` addresses belonging to a domain you do _not_ have under your control. Which reads: it is a problem for people explicitly trying to forge messages.

Comment: I need set -1 for you answer but not to be. Because bad way use mail and manualy set header, batter way use php library for it. and correct `From: "Name from sendler" <username@domain.com>`

Comment: Correct, Always better to setup smtp server.